# Linking two MySQL tables containing pipe delimited characters were the only physical link is there relative location

Tags: mysql, substring, comparison, mysql-5.1

I have two MYSQL tables *Products* and *Prices*. Both tables are populated via a webform that creates a pipe delimited value for the options that the end user has selected. This process and the initial output cannot be changed.

So if User1 selects 3 products, they will have a string with three products and two pipes. If User 2 selects 7 products they will have a string with 7 products and 6 pipes.

The separate *prices* table will then have corresponding pipe delimited values for the prices for each of the items selected by the user.

I am wanting to attribute the price to the product, but the only linking value is there location within a pipe delimited string whose length fluctuates based on the number of items selected.

**Products Table**

| Account ID | Options |
| --- | --- |
| s001 | Cat|Dog|Cow|Sheep |
| s002 | Cat|Dog|Cow|Sheep |
| s003 | Cat|Dog|Sheep |
| s004 | Cat|Dog|Sheep |
| s005 | Cat|Dog|Sheep |
| s006 | Cat|Dog|Cow|Sheep |
| s007 | Cat|Dog|Cow|Pig|Goat|Seagull|Sheep |
| s008 | Duck |
| s009 | Pig|Goat|Seagull|Sheep |
| s010 | Cat|Dog|Cow|Sheep|Seal |

**Prices Table**

| Account ID | optionsdiscounts |
| --- | --- |
| s001 | -40.00|0.00|-40.00|0.00 |
| s002 | -40.00|0.00|-40.00|0.00 |
| s003 | -40.00|0.00|0.00 |
| s004 | -5.50|0.00|0.00 |
| s005 | -40.00|0.00|0.00 |
| s006 | -40.00|0.00|0.00 |
| s007 | -15.00|0.00|-15.00|-15.00|0.00|-15.00|0.00 |
| s008 | -13.85 |
| s009 | -33.71|0.00|-33.71|0.00 |
| s010 | -40.00|0.00|-40.00|0.00 |

So using the tables above I need to say that for:

- s001, Cat is -40, and Cow is -40
- s005, Sheep (Position 3) is 0.00
- s006, sheep (Position 4) is 0.00
- s008, Duck is -13.85

The location of each product can be in a different location for each account, as seen by the sheep product for S001,S005,S007 where it appears at positions 4, 3 and 7 respectively.

There are currently 13 individual 'animal' products that can be selected by the user and currently in the DB there are around 50 variations of product strings that exist.

There are currently around 2,500 rows of records that I am needing to report on with this criteria, but the DB table contains around 1.9 million records (the remaining records have a level of consistency that I can work with), it is the remaining 2,500 that have a odd format.

Using the substring_index in MySQL I can split the string based on the delimitator to then have a column for each of the individual data items:

**Product**

```
    case when 0<= LENGTH(options) - LENGTH(REPLACE(options, '|', '')) then
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(options, '|', 1), '|', -1) ELSE null  end as op1
```

| Account ID | op1 | op2 | op3 | op4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s001 | Cat | Dog | Cow | Sheep |

I can also carry out the same function on the **Prices** table to then provide each data item as a separate column.

The issue I am having is that **I am unable to find away to attribute the price item to the description of the product item based on its location**

I do have the option to use SSIS to carry out transformation on the data, I can also save the data to an SQL-server database if an option is available in that language.

Comment: A major design error I am afraid. Design the database as a Relational database should be and these issue will never bother you again. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) TL/DR **YES**

Comment: There does not seem much point in storing the Zero discounts. Wouldn't it be better to say if I can find a discount use it, otherwise the discount is zero

Comment: I am sorry but, whomsoever designed (if thats the word) this database has left you with a complete and utter mess.

Comment: If you can somehow transform that out into unique (account, animal) columns with a 3rd column for price, I'd start that way. As mentioned in a previous comment, I would not have any entries with a 0 discount, for the same reason.

Comment: yes I fully understand its a complete and utter mess, but this is the way that the database is designed and what we are stuck with it and we cannot make any changes to it. I've been trying some transformations in SSIS to get around the issue, but ive not had any sucess gettign to were i need it to be

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: @BillKarwin the db is at 5.1.73

Comment: Okay, I have a solution for MySQL 8.0, but you're using a MySQL version that was end of life in 2013. Forget it, just burn it down and start over.

Comment: @BillKarwin I wish I could but unfortunately I am stuck with this db. I can mirror the data into a 2016 or 2019 SQL server db if thats an easier proposition

Comment: Do you want me to post my solution for MySQL 8.0 as an answer, knowing that it doesn't work in MySQL 5.1? It might at least give you ideas for how to solve it in SQL Server.

Comment: if there is a solution, even for a later version of MYSQL it might be better than nothing and give a starting point of how to fix this mess